# How to add style to excel header? - Angular

Tags: angular, npm, xlsx

I am inserting the data with the "json_to_sheet" method but I want to add a style to the header.

Lyricism has been used XLSX
`import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

```
document(){

  let list:any =[
    {
      id: 1,
      user:"Alex",
      email:"alex@hotmail.com", 
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      user:"Luz",
      email:"luz@hotmail.com", 
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      user:"Roberto",
      email:"roberto@hotmail.com", 
    },
  ]

  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(list);
  var wsCol = [
    {wch:5},  // A
    {wch:13}, // B
    {wch:20}, // C
  ];
  ws['!cols'] = wsCol; 

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'sheet');
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, "fileName.xlsx");
}
```

Result sought:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k12J2.png)